# ASP.NET 4.5 ZipFile class how to download and open zip from FTP

Tags: asp.net, ftp, zip, ftpwebrequest

My overall goal is to grab a zip file from my ftp, open it on the fly, read the content for a specific field in the excel file (there will only ever be one file in any zip).

So far I have been successful in connecting to my ftp with ftpwebrequest and I can download a the file to a local folder (not my desired workflow but I am taking a 'baby steps' approach)

I have found that in Asp.Net 4.5 a class was introduced called ZipFile and it seems to have a method to open and read a zip but I can not seem to have it accept my ftp path as a valid path.

Here is what I have for downloading.

```
var file = f.Element("FILE_PATH").Value;
                string ftpHost = "ftp.com";

                var URI = @"ftp://" + ftpHost + "/download/" + file;
                var UserName = @"ftp@mysite.com";

                FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(URI);
                ftp.UsePassive = true;
                ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, "Password");
                ftp.UseBinary = true;
                ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

                FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
                string theFile = ftpResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();

                Stream responseStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                FileStream writer = new FileStream(@"C:\websites\" + file, FileMode.Create);

                long length = response.ContentLength;
                int bufferSize = 2048;
                int readCount;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

                readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                responseStream.Close();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                writer.Close();
```

I have tried to implement the following to open and read the zip. I placed this block after the line creating the string "theFile" for lack of knowing a better home for it. This returns and error that the path is invalid.

```
.... FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
                    string theFile = ftpResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(theFile))
                    {
                        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry zfile in archive.Entries)
                        {
                            var FileName = zfile.Name;

                        }
                    }
```

how might I accomplish opening and reading this file from the ftp?

Comment: Unsure if you're open to alternatives. If you are I highly recommend [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). Makes life so much easier....

Comment: I though it would be nice if I could get it done without 3rd party but I am open to alternative. i will give DotNetZip a try